# Use of CakePHP's HttpSocket or PHP's cURL to crawl several sites from a search page

Tags: php, cakephp, curl, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am going to use CakePHP to build an application that allows users to search for a keyword, ie. milk, and then I would automatically search local online stores for best pricing on milk, ie. walmart, shaws, stop&shop, etc. (*Note: this is a hypothetical situation, exemplifying what I need accomplished*), and then I would display the results to the user.

I want to take advantage of CakePHP's HttpSocket library to accomplish this instead of cURL.

I will need to have this setup as multi-thread so I can display the results quicker, but for performance's sake, where is the best place to make these call, ie Controller? Basically, I am looking for your insight into the best approach to have something like that work, considering it needs to be multi-thread, and fast.

I have not used CakePHP's HttpSocket library before, but I have looked thru it and tested it quickly and it seems to be very powerful. What is your take on that? Does it compare performance-wise to PHP's cURL?

Your insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI: in no way is cURL multi-threaded ... it can be non-blocking, but not multi-threaded.

Comment: How about the cURL multi-handle? Could that be considered multi-threaded? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Comment: "in no way" is pretty explicit language ... I don't have a more explicit way to express it, but will try again ... cURL is in _no way_ multi-threaded, the curl multi interface is non-blocking, _not multi-threaded_ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL is faster than any plain php implementation like the CakePHP socket is.

Controller is the wrong place, model or a custom datasource would be the proper place. You can request multiple sites at the same time and wait X seconds until you cancel the requests that have not responded in time. Also I would cache the results so that you don't have to request the price each time.

Depending on how often the prices change it might be a much better idea to just query all your shops one or two times per day or hourly for example using a shell and update the prices in your database.

Comment: Custom datasource is certainly a great approach to take, which I was not thinking about. I will definitely take that approach and implement it for this project. I wanted to avoid using the Database although I agree is a much better idea, mainly because of the sheer amount of products that are available. However, I may take your suggestion and develop a database system ontop of using the database to crawl when needed. Thank you for your help!